# Macro to call a function

Tags: c, macros, arguments, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I need a macro (or a function, but preferably a macro) that takes a function name and an unlimited number of arguments, then passes the arguments to the function. Let's say this macro is `MACROFOO`.

```
#define MACROFOO(function, ...)     /* what do I put here?? */

int foo_bar(int x, int y)
{
    // do stuff
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 5;

    MACROFOO(foo_bar, x, y);    // calls foo_bar(x, y)
}
```

How could I define such a macro? I thought of doing something like:

```
#define MACROFOO(function, args...)     (function)(args)
```

but it looks like that passes `...` to the function, instead of the actual arguments. What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can expand the `...` of variadic macros with `__VA_ARGS__`.

Example:

```
#define MACROFOO(function, ...)  (function)(__VA_ARGS__)

MACROFOO(printf, "hello world%c", '!') 
/*^ expands to: (printf)("hello world%c", '!') */
```

---

Note: As you probably know, the parentheses prevent the `function` argument from being expanded as a macro (if it is a macro).

I.e.,

```
#define BAR(...) myprintf(__VA_ARGS__)
MACROFOO(BAR, "hello world%c", '!')
```

will expand to:

```
(BAR)("hello world%c", '!')
```

with the parentheses and

```
myprintf("hello world%c", '!')
```

if your remove them.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either the standard variable argument `__VA_ARGS__`:

```
#define MACROFOO(function, ...)  (function)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

or if you like a more descriptive name  you can use this GNU CPP extension by writing a name immediately before `...` :

```
#define MACROFOO(function, parameters...)  (function)(parameters)
```

---

[**GNU CPP Section 3.6:**](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.1/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

> (...)
>   **Variadic macros are a new feature in C99**. GNU CPP has supported them
>   for a long time, but only with a named variable argument (‘args...’,
>   not ‘...’ and __VA_ARGS__).
>
> If you are concerned with portability to
>   previous versions of GCC, you should use only named variable
>   arguments. On the other hand, if you are concerned with portability to
>   other conforming implementations of C99, you should use only
>   __VA_ARGS__.