# Why can't I paste an object-like macro to a function?

Tags: c, macros

I've defined an object-like macro and a function-like macro (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42654888/7656486) question).

```
#define SYSTEM windows
#define CALL(function, ...)   (function)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Given this definition, `CALL(foo, arg1, arg2)` turns into `foo(arg1, arg2)`.

I want `CALL(foo, args)` to turn into `x__foo(args)`, `x` being whatever `SYSTEM` is defined to.

I have tried:

```
#define CALL(function, ...)   SYSTEM##__function(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CALL(function, ...)   (SYSTEM)##__##(function)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CALL(function, ...)   ((SYSTEM)##__##(function)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

They all result in compiler errors.

How can I define `CALL` so that it concatenates the value of `SYSTEM`, `__`, and the value of `function`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to need a few more levels of indirection to concatenate (paste) those values. The C preprocessor attempts to paste *exactly* what it sees. If what it's seeing is a macro or a value passed to a function, it doesn't realize that.

- `MACRO##SOMETHINGELSE` will produce `MACROSOMETHINGELSE`.
- `(MACRO)##SOMETHINGELSE` will result in an error upon compilation, because the preprocessor is attempting to paste the parenthesis.
- `SOMETHINGELSE##VALUEPASSEDTOMACRO` will result in `SOMETHINGVALUEPASSEDTOMACRO`.

None of these are what you want, obviously. To add the indirection necessary to concatenate object-like-macro values and values passed to a function-like-macro, use two more definitions.

```
#define _cat(x, y) x ## y
#define cat(x, y) _cat(x, y)
```

Then you can define `CALL` to fit your needs.

```
#define SYSTEM windows
#define CALL(function, ...)   cat(cat(SYSTEM, __), function) (__VA_ARGS__)
```

Writing `CALL(foobar, x, y)` calls `windows__foobar(x, y)` as desired.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define SYSTEM windows
#define PASTE_CALL(prefix, function, ...) prefix ## __ ## function(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL_CALL(prefix, function, ...) PASTE_CALL(prefix, function, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CALL(function, ...) EVAL_CALL(SYSTEM, function, __VA_ARGS__)

CALL(foo, arg1, arg2)
```

As desired, this generates:

```
# 1 "paste.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "paste.c"





windows__foo(arg1, arg2)
```